# Uncertainty of an integral estimate

Tags: estimation, standard-error, error, integral, error-propagation

I am making the following estimate:

\begin{equation}
    \langle f \rangle \simeq \int_0^1 \left[ f(x) \cdot K(x) \right] \; \text{d}x
\end{equation}
where

- $f$ is an unknown function, possibly $f(x) \in [-0.5, 0.5]$, of $x\in [0,1]$,
- $K$ is a known normalized function that loosely resembles a Gaussian which is peaked at some location in the interval $[0,1]$ and satisfies $\int K=1$, and
- $\langle f \rangle$ is an estimate of $f$ at the peak of $K$.

I want to know the uncertainty of $\langle f \rangle$.

$K$ can be non-Gaussian in that it doesn't necessarily monotonically decrease away from the peak. It might have large amplitude at random elsewhere. I can access and inspect this function.

My idea is to estimate it in a Monte Carlo fashion: that is, generate random polynomials, pretend they are $f$, check the residuals, and numerically calculate uncertainties based off of that. However, I don't know if this is a good idea, and it seems like there should be some better way to get an estimate.

It would be acceptable to make some reasonable assumptions based on $f$. For example, it could be continuous, smooth, bounded in magnitude between say $[-0.5,0.5]$, or whatever else may prove necessary.

Comment: What's your question? Whether the approach you propose is valid or the original, "what's the uncertainty of $<f>$"? You might consider moving the second half into an answer to your own question if you make progress with that approach.

Comment: My question is: What's the uncertainty of $\langle f \rangle$? I am furthermore wondering if the approach I proposed is a good one to estimate it, or if there is a better/more straightforward way to tackle this problem.

Comment: Got it! That helps. I am asking only for clarity. One smarter than I may answer yet.

Comment: do you have any data on $f$, like you observe some pairs $(x_i, f(x_i))$ possibly corrupted by noise? For your approach with random polynomials you're flirting with the idea of having a prior over functions and then sampling from that distribution; you could try to make that more formal with something like a gaussian process. If you have any evaluations of $f$ this would go nicely

Comment: You *define* ⟨f⟩ as the integral, but then claim (your third bullet point) that "⟨f⟩ is an estimate of f at the peak of K." I can't quite square the two. That said, I think any results will be heavily dependent on the regularity of $f$, in particular the existance and continuity of the second derivative and any bounds for $|f''|$. And what is "reasonable" about such assumptions will very much depend on your problem, so we can't say which assumptions are reasonable and which aren't. Can you clarify?

Comment: @StephanKolassa Perhaps I should have used $\simeq$ instead of $=$. It's easy to see that if you have a function that looks like a Gaussian and another function, the integral of their product will be an estimate of the other function at the location of the Gaussian.

Comment: @StephanKolassa as far as what is reasonable, what I can say is that it's a physical function (in fact, an unknown astrophysical function), so anything that might be reasonable "in real life" would be reasonable here. Existence and continuity are perfectly fine.

Comment: Maybe take derivative of $ \int_0^t \left[ f(x) \cdot K(x) \right] \; \text{d}x$, and do error propagation?

Comment: @Carl how do I do that when $f(x)$ is unknown?

Comment: Does $f(x)$ have any experimental observations; bounds or outcomes? If it does not, I doubt your question can be answered. Why do you say its range is (0, 1) then ask about (-0.5, 0.5)?

Comment: @Carl I am trying to estimate $f(x)$ at certain points using this expression. The function itself is otherwise unknown.

Comment: @Carl Not its range, its domain. $x\in (0,1),\; f(x) \in (-0.5, 0.5)$

Comment: Is $K$ continuous or discrete? Is it a collection of outcomes? You want confidence intervals on $\langle f \rangle$, yet it is unclear how $\langle f \rangle$ is estimated. What are you asking for? The CI's or the mean or both?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is exactly what you want but I think it's related. Bayesian quadrature (and more generally probabilistic numerics) phrase integration as inferential problem. Here're some slides introducing the topic: http://probabilistic-numerics.org/assets/pdf/nips2015_probint/roman_talk.pdf. If you google around about probabilistic numerics I think you'll be able to find something close to your problem